# PHP loop array_search to whitelist

Tags: php

Trying to whitelist a query string against known values. Not getting expected answer. The array I'm receiving from `$_GET` is exactly as expected and shown below:

```
$get = array('petTypeFK' =>
             [
                 0 => 1,
                 1 => 2
             ],
             'recipeName' =>
             [
                 0 => 'Chicken Alfredo',
                 1 => 'Lemon Salmon'
             ],
             'comments' =>
             [
                 0 => 'NULL',
                 1 => 'NULL'
             ]);
```

The whitelist is taken from the database based on the table session variable, and I receive an array like below as expected:

```
$fieldWhitelist = array(0 => 'recipeName', 1 => 'petTypeFK', 2 => 'comments');
```

I isolate the key from the `$_GET` array using `foreach()`, and then check each one against the whitelist using `array_search`.

```
foreach ($get as $field => $groupedValues) {
    if (array_search($field, $fieldWhitelist, false)) {
        echo "$field \t true";
    } else {
        echo "$field \t false";
    }
}
```

I'm expecting `true` across the board, but `recipeName` winds up `false` despite it's an identical string.

Comment: `array_search` can return `0`. And `if(0)...` will just go to the else part. You should use something like this: `if (array_search($field, $fieldWhitelist, false) !== false)`

Comment: Get it back for doing a whitelist - a very wise move. Consider posting the final code on the https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/php for the review, just in case.